# Recurrence formula for sums

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations

I know that $$\sum_{n_{k-1}=1}^{n_k} \sum_{n_{k-2}=1}^{n_{k-1}} ... \sum_{n_0=1}^{n_1} 1=\frac{1}{k!}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} (n_k+i)=\frac{(n_k+k-1)!}{k!(n_k-1)!}=\binom{n_k+k-1}{k}$$

But what if I have:

1/ $\sum_{n_{k-1}=1}^{n_k} \sum_{n_{k-2}=1}^{n_{k-1}} ... \sum_{n_0=1}^{n_1} n_0$ ?

2/ $\sum_{n_{k-1}=1}^{n_k} \sum_{n_{k-2}=1}^{n_{k-1}} ... \sum_{n_0=1}^{n_1} n_0(n_0+1)$ ?

Is there any formula to simplify it?

Comment: The limits have no dependence on $i$ (it is a constant, not a variable, it isn't mentioned in any of the limits of the sums), so you can factor $i$ out.

Comment: Mea culpa, I have edited my question, I meant that $i$ was an index of the sum so I replaced it with $n_0$.

Comment: Here is a hint for the first one: Try writing $n_0$ as $\sum_{i=1}^{n_0}$  A similar trick will work for the second question, but writing it in terms of a double sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's identity
\begin{align*}
A_k(N)=\sum_{n_{k-1}=1}^{N} \sum_{n_{k-2}=1}^{n_{k-1}} \cdots\sum_{n_0=1}^{n_1} 1=\binom{N+k-1}{k}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
depends on the upper limit  $N (\geq 1)$ of the outermost sum and the number $k$ of the involved $\Sigma$-symbols  indicated by the naming of the bounded variables $n_0,\ldots,n_{k-1}$. In fact the  naming of the bounded indices is not essential, as the right hand side of (1) shows.

We can calculate both expressions OP is asking for by using (1).

> Since
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n_0=1}^{n_1}1=n_1
> \end{align*}
>   we obtain from (1) for $N\geq 1$
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n_{k}=1}^{N}\sum_{n_{k-1}=1}^{n_{k}} \cdots\sum_{n_1=1}^{n_2} \color{blue}{n_1}
> &=\sum_{n_{k}=1}^{N} \sum_{n_{k-1}=1}^{n_{k}} \cdots\sum_{n_1=1}^{n_2} \color{blue}{\sum_{n_0=1}^{n_1}1}\\
> &=A_{k+1}(N)\\
> &=\binom{N+k}{k+1}
> \end{align*}

$$ $$

> Since
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n_1=1}^{n_2}\sum_{n_0=1}^{n_1}1=\sum_{n_1=1}^{n_2}n_1=\frac{n_2(n_2+1)}{2}
> \end{align*}
>   we obtain from (1) for $N\geq 1$
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n_{k+1}=1}^{N}&\sum_{n_{k}=1}^{n_{k+1}} \cdots\sum_{n_2=1}^{n_3} \color{blue}{\frac{n_2(n_2+1)}{2}}\\
> &=\sum_{n_{k+1}=1}^{N} \sum_{n_{k-1}=1}^{n_{k}} \cdots\sum_{n_2=1}^{n_3} \color{blue}{\sum_{n_1=1}^{n_2}\sum_{n_0=1}^{n_1}1}\\
> &=A_{k+2}(N)\\
> &=\binom{N+k+1}{k+2}
> \end{align*}

Comment: With this problem it is important to get the notation right even though it is very simple. My computation does not quite match your post.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: In fact I think that our computations match. I've updated my answer to better see what's going on. Maybe you might want  to check my answer again.  (I'm pretty sure you will, so thanks in advance. :-))

Comment: I accepted these as an answer because I find this proof much easier than the one of @MarkoRiedel though his is very interesting.

Comment: @Arty: Good to see my answer is useful. Thanks for your nice reply! :-)

Answer (score 4):

For the first one we introduce for $k\ge 1$ the generating function

$$g_k(z) = \sum_{n_k\ge 1} z^{n_k}
\sum_{n_{k-1}=1}^{n_k}
\sum_{n_{k-2}=1}^{n_{k-1}}
\cdots
\sum_{n_{0}=1}^{n_{1}} 1.$$

We immediately have

$$g_1(z) = \sum_{n_1\ge 1} z^{n_1} \sum_{n_{0}=1}^{n_{1}} 1
= \sum_{n_1\ge 1} n_1 z^{n_1} = \frac{z}{(1-z)^2}.$$

We also have

$$g_k(z) = \sum_{n_k\ge 1} z^{n_k}
\sum_{n_{k-1}=1}^{n_k} [w^{n_{k-1}}] g_{k-1}(w)
\\ = \sum_{n_{k-1}\ge 1} \sum_{n_k\ge n_{k-1}}
z^{n_{k}}[w^{n_{k-1}}] g_{k-1}(w)
\\ = \sum_{n_{k-1}\ge 1} [w^{n_{k-1}}] g_{k-1}(w)
 \sum_{n_k\ge n_{k-1}} z^{n_{k}}
\\ = \sum_{n_{k-1}\ge 1} [w^{n_{k-1}}] g_{k-1}(w)
\frac{z^{n_{k-1}}}{1-z}
\\ = \frac{1}{1-z}
\sum_{n_{k-1}\ge 1} z^{n_{k-1}} [w^{n_{k-1}}] g_{k-1}(w)
\\ = \frac{1}{1-z} g_{k-1}(z)
= \frac{1}{(1-z)^2} g_{k-2}(z)
= \frac{1}{(1-z)^3} g_{k-3}(z)
\\ = \cdots = \frac{1}{(1-z)^{k-1}} g_1(z)
= \frac{z}{(1-z)^{k+1}}.$$

Extracting coefficients we find

$$[z^{n_k}] \frac{z}{(1-z)^{k+1}}
= [z^{n_k-1}] \frac{1}{(1-z)^{k+1}}
= {n_k+k-1\choose k}$$

as claimed. The second case has

$$g_1(z) = \sum_{n_1\ge 1} z^{n_1} \sum_{n_{0}=1}^{n_{1}} n_0
= \sum_{n_1\ge 1} z^{n_1} \frac{1}{2} n_1 (n_1+1)
= \frac{z}{(1-z)^3}.$$

Extracting coefficients we  see that compared to the first  one $k$ is
replaced by $k+1$ and we obtain

$${n_k+k\choose k+1}.$$

The third case yields

$$g_1(z) = \sum_{n_1\ge 1} z^{n_1} \sum_{n_{0}=1}^{n_{1}} n_0 (n_0+1)
= \sum_{n_1\ge 1} z^{n_1} \frac{1}{3} n_1 (n_1+1) (n_1+2)
= \frac{2z}{(1-z)^4}.$$

Extracting coefficients once more we obtain

$$2\times {n_k+k+1\choose k+2}.$$

Here is an example for the third formula.

```
> seq(add(add(add(n0*(n0+1), n0=1..n1), n1=1..n2), n2=1..n3), n3=1..10);
                2, 12, 42, 112, 252, 504, 924, 1584, 2574, 4004

> seq(2*binomial(n3+3+1,3+2), n3=1..10);
                2, 12, 42, 112, 252, 504, 924, 1584, 2574, 4004
```